# Bluetooth support in QuickBlox sdk Android

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am currently using Quick Blox android Sdk version 3.2.0 for video and audio calling in my application. Everything is working fine but when I connect my mobile with blue-tooth device nothing happened while calling i.e I am not being able to use blue-tooth for calling purpose. I have searched a lot the documentation of the sdk but nothing is there about blue-tooth support in android. Does anyone knows how do I overcome this problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue . Didn't find anything yet .